# Changing Postman request name from prerequest script

Tags: api, testing, postman

I'm currently trying to implement few Postman requests with CSV data sources. 
For instance let assume I have request named "Open as user".
In csv file, I have bunch of user credentials with description field that describes user role.
I would like to have the ability to change request names to reflect each user roles.
For instance, if the request is made as the admin user I would like request name in reports and runner to be  "Open as user admin".

In documentation, I've found pm.info.requestName variable but seems it is read-only.
I put following in Pre-request Script

`pm.info.requestName = "1";
console.log(pm.info.requestName);`

but got "Open as user" value instead of assigned "1".

Have anyone tried to do the same trick or know whether it is possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you can't do that. pm.request object is available only after request execution. I even think that you can't access the request name the way you want (I though I would find it in the 'id' member, but it was empty)

Have a look [here](http://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/Request.html#~definition) to see what's available in terms of members and methods concerning the request object.

You may find another way of proceeding (maybe duplicate your test, rename it with admin and, under proper condition, launch the admin request instead of the common user request ? it's kind of a hassle just for a test name)

I think about something else: you could just customize your assertions label, that's what I do to have 'readable' test names in TFS reports. In the Tests tab :

```
test_name = "[ "+ request.name + " ] - ";
```

and for each assertion (example):

```
tests[test_name + "Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;
```

This gives, in the response Tests tab, something like :

```
PASS [Get all configuration]-Status code is 200
```

Under a particular condition, you can replace request.name with a custom string or do request.name + "admin" ...

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution to this as well and i have solved it in the following way:

- Use the 'Pre-request Script' to determine what role the user has.
- Set the url to a environment- or global-variable
- Use that url in the request, like {{url}}
- Clear the environment- or global-variable in the 'Tests' tab

In my case i used the environment variable to get the environment, instead of you, using the data variables.

```
var environment = pm.environment.get("environment");
var url;
switch(environment) {
case "test":
    url = pm.globals.get("test-url");
    break;
case "acc":
    url = pm.globals.get("acc-url");
    break;
case "prod":
    url = pm.globals.get("prod-url");
    break;
default:
    url = pm.globals.get("test-url");
    break;
}

pm.environment.set("url", url);
```

Hope this helps!